# ctags: prevent jump to first result for ctrl + ]

Tags: vim, vi, ctags, cscope

I wanted to prevent jumping to the first result without user intervention upon <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>]</kbd> (or left click) in `vim`. In effect, when I click (<kbd>ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>]</kbd>) on an identifier, it should list all the occurance (like tag search) and should jump to the selection (1,2..) when user input 1,2 etc. I remember using it by setting an option in `.vimrc` (something like `cscope` mode), but couldn't recollect now.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [tag-matchlist](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#tag-matchlist)?

Comment: the behavior of left mouse click and ctrl+] should be same as g] (from the tag-matchlist documentation.i did it previously with a setting in .vimrc, rather than key map. maybe i installed cscope as well, and used them together.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want `g]`. It shows the matching tags.

While I don't think there's an option to make `Ctrl+]` show a list if there's only one result, if you set `cscopetag` and `set cscopetagorder=0`, then you'll search your cscope database which will likely show more results than your tags. (Especially if you're using C++ and have -`-c++-kinds=+p` which will include function prototypes *and* the implementations -- you almost always have two of the same thing. I use that setting because it's required by omnicppcomplete.)

You still won't get a list if you only have one result. For that, you'd have to make maps to swap `Ctrl+]` and `g]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following line in .vimrc

```
map <C-]> g]
```